# order by usage with multiple options

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL query where I want to order the database on type, order and category. Can I have query having all these three?

```
select * from t_person where name=xyz order by type,category,order
```

Comment: yes you can, do you have any problems?

Comment: Your last column name is reserved word and can cause problems.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SQL and belongs on [dba.se].

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson, this question is about a SQL query and is more on-topic here than a forum about administering databases.

Comment: @BradRem [dba.se] also allows questions regarding SQL. To be more on topic here, the OP would need to show the program code surrounding this query.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

Use `""` (double quotes) to escape the reserved keyword **order**

```
select * from t_person where name='xyz'
order by type,category,"order"
```

Comment: better yet, don't use a column with a reseved word as its name.

Answer (score 1):

Use double quote for correct query:

```
select * from t_person where name='xyz' order by type,category,"order"
```